# How to fix segment fault in unix socket programming?

Tags: c, sockets, http, unix

I can't find where is segment fault occurs in this source code.

I'm making unix http server in C lang.
using pthread, and response function (int this code, refered())

I tried checking buffer sizes(headers, requests, file, path).
and changed pthread to fork(), but its doesn't matter.

It worked well when I use my test html files.
but it breaks in unexpected times.

```c
while (1)
    {
        new_socket = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        if ((*new_socket = accept(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, &addrlen))==-1){
            perror("accept");
            exit(1);
        }
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, threadfunc, (void*)new_socket);
        pthread_detach(tid);
    }
```

this is accept part in main().

```c
    recv(*new_socket, buffer, 1024, 0);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    strcpy(getPath,basicpath);

    strtok(buffer," ");
    strcpy(openfilename,strtok(NULL," "));

    if(strcmp(openfilename,"/") == 0)
        strcpy(openfilename,"/index.html");

    strcat(getPath,openfilename);

    refered(*new_socket,getPath);

    free(vargp);
    return NULL;
```

```c
    if(((fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY)) < -1) || (fstat(fd, &filestat) < 0))
    {
        printf("Error in measuring the size of the file\n");
    }
    else
        sprintf(filesize, "%zd", filestat.st_size);

    if((fp = fopen(filename,"r")) ==  NULL)
    {
        strcpy (header_buff, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");
        write (ns, header_buff, strlen(header_buff));
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy (header_buff, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: ");
        strcat (header_buff, filesize);
        strcat (header_buff, "\r\nContent-Type: */* \r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");
        fread (file_buff, sizeof(char), filestat.st_size + 1, fp);
        write (ns, header_buff, strlen(header_buff));
        write (ns, file_buff, filestat.st_size);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    close(ns);
```

and this is response part.

I want to find where Segmentation fault (core dumped) occurs.

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: a) You can check the core dump file - it will show you where the crash happens b) You can use a debugger - it will stop and display  where the crash happens c) you can use printf to narrow down where the crash happens - simply put a printf between every statement.

Comment: thanks @4386427 . I found error in recv(*new_socket, buffer, 1024, 0);
web browser requested twice times. and then new_socket corrupted.
so buffer get empty character buffer.

Comment: `strtok(buffer," ");` You are assuming NUL-terminated strings. The buffer is **not NUL-terminated**.